# Inexplicable white/blank space in Android app, not showing in layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, whitespace, android-constraintlayout

The preview looks fine, but the app runs differently. In the layout inspector, there is simply nothing where this weird white space is. It seems to be a problem with ConstraintLayout + ViewPager. I had the same issue in three places, all with same ViewPager, 0dp vertical size setup. I have solved by converting ConstraintLayouts into LinearLayouts. But the question is why do I need to regress to a LinearLayout? I originally wrote the UI with ConstraintLayout, and ViewPager, it was fine. Somewhere along the way, without touching the code, things turned weird and this blank space showed up. As if something in Android UI rendering changed under the hood. Anyone have any idea what it is, or how to solve while keeping a ConstraintLayout?

Here is the layout inspector image of the app running on a device. I have clearly marked the problematic white space with my mouse calligraphy skills.

[image: Live app UI]

Here is the layout preview for the following xml code, note UI elements fill the screen, no white space after the bottom toolbar in this view, unlike live app. Don't mind the colour difference, the app changes colours at run time.

[image: Layout preview]

fragment_layout.xml (Between green and marked blank space in live app image, the rest of UI is from activity, but I know that's not the problem, so won't add the xml for that)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.order.OrderBuildFragment"
    >

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/order_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/order_viewpager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/order_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/order_tabs"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/build_order_bottom_toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/build_order_bottom_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/order_viewpager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_service_point_spinner_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/service_point"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/order_toolbar_service_point_spinner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            />
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/order_toolbar_service_point_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/order_service_point_spinner_label"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_textView_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@{@string/currency_symbol + viewModel.price}"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/order_toolbar_button_more"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"
                tools:text="$999.99"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/order_toolbar_button_more"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="moreButtonAction"
                android:text="@string/more"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/order_toolbar_button_send"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/order_textView_price"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/order_toolbar_button_send"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="sendButtonAction"
                android:text="@{viewModel.sendButtonText}"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/order_toolbar_button_more"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/build_order_guideline_service_point_and_action_buttons"
                tools:text="@string/send"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/build_order_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.loading)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My Linear layout solution simply included replacing ConstraintLayout with a LinearLayout, removing all constraints from child elements and adding orientation: "vertical" (of course) plus putting layout_weight: 1 in the ViewPager element. If that helps anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2`.
This specific version is known to cause issues like this.

Update to the latest version (`'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'` at the time of writing).

Comment: I was on latest stable release 1.1.3. I see there was a known issue and 2.0.0-beta6 fixed it a month ago. Didn't even think to look on there. I've had this problem so long. Finally sorted. Thanks!